# make gives "commands commence before first target"

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm attempting to use this makefile, and entered it in as it was given, but as it is below, it threw a "missing separator" error for line 2.

```
/usr/bin/gcc -pipe -Wall -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native  pidigits.c -o pidigits.gcc_run -lgmp
rm pidigits.c
```

I looked that error up and added a tab before the 'rm' operator, but then it gave the "commands commence before first target" error.
I tried adding tabs before each line, as well as a tab before -pipe and before rm, but nothing works.
Any suggestions? I'm sure I'm just missing something blatantly obvious... this is my first time trying to write a makefile.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more lines from your makefile?

Comment: That's all I have. Never made a makefile before so don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: It looks more like a shell script. So you might want to run it with `sh makefile`. If you actually need a makefile, I suggest you to study at least basics at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [{Makefile Error} "commands commence before first target. Stop."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238223/makefile-error-commands-commence-before-first-target-stop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read this properly, you want your makefile to looke like:

```
foo_rule:
\t/usr/bin/gcc -pipe -Wall -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=native  pidigits.c -o pidigits.gcc_run -lgmp; \
rm pidigits.c
```

Where \t is a tab.

Comment: Is the \ at the end of the long line supposed to be a \t or just a \ ?Thanks!

Comment: Ok I added the elements you suggested. Now it throws an error about the command line option -03. I've had a similar experience before. Do I need to install something else on my system?
Sorry if these are dumb questions.

Comment: @Johonn, that's just a trailing slash. Make actually invokes a separate shell for each command within a rule. The trailing slash joins the second line to the first so it all runs as one command.

Would you share the O3 error? My version of GCC supports this level of optimization.

Comment: Ok I just removed the -03. It works now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the response before. I didn't realize it was an O and not an 0, that would probably be the problem.