# Makefile: Remove single object file

Tags: makefile

I want to delete one single object file `version.o` from the directory `myobj_x`.

I used the following command:

```
(tab)-rm obj_kt_rfgw/version.o
```

But now i getting an error:

```
Makefile:8: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

Comment: That error means that you have that recipe line before the first target line. That needs to be *in* the recipe for a target to work. You haven't shown us enough of your makefile for us to be able to help any more than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [{Makefile Error} "commands commence before first target. Stop."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238223/makefile-error-commands-commence-before-first-target-stop)

Comment: ok, i added the line after the traget **all** and the file is deleting. Everytime i want to delete the object file **version.o**, so i can be rebuild it. But now it will don't compile.